# LWIP STM32CubeF7 to communicate with TCP ethernet to Java URL connection class application

Tags: java, c++, tcp, stm32, urlconnection

I am trying to create a Java application that reads data of a server using TCP. The server is an[STM32F4DISCOVERY](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) SOC board from STM32. I am using the [LwIP_HTTP_Server_Netconn_RTOS](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF7/tree/master/Projects/STM32746G-Discovery/Applications/LwIP/LwIP_HTTP_Server_Netconn_RTOS) example application as an example.

Here is the important part of the code of the LWIP, that handles the GET requests. The server works well on the browser.

```html
/* Put the connection into LISTEN state */
netconn_listen(conn);

while(1) 
{
  /* accept any icoming connection */
  accept_err = netconn_accept(conn, &newconn);
  if(accept_err == ERR_OK)
  {
    /* serve connection */
    http_server_serve(newconn);
    /* delete connection */
    netconn_delete(newconn);
  }
}


static void http_server_serve(struct netconn *conn) 
{
  .
  .
  
  
  if ((buflen >=5) && (strncmp(buf, "GET /", 5) == 0))
  {
                if (strncmp((char const *)buf,"GET /STM32F7xx",27)==0)
            {
              fs_open(&file, "/STM32F7xx.html");
              netconn_write(conn, (const unsigned char*)(file.data), (size_t)file.len, NETCONN_NOCOPY);
              fs_close(&file);
            }
      ... other if stats to handle other /routes
      
      else if (strncmp(buf, "GET /test", 9) == 0)
            {
              DynWebPage2(conn);
            }
   }
   
void DynWebPage2(struct netconn *conn)
{
  portCHAR PAGE_BODY[512];
  portCHAR PAGE_BEGIN[512];
  portCHAR pagehits[10] = {0};

  memset(PAGE_BODY, 0,512);
  memset(PAGE_BEGIN, 0,512);

  /* Update the hit count */
  nPageHits++;
  sprintf(pagehits, "%d", (int)nPageHits);
  strcat(PAGE_BODY, "helloworld");
  strcat((char *)PAGE_BEGIN, "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">");
  strcat((char *)PAGE_BEGIN, "<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">");

  /* Send the dynamically generated page */
  netconn_write(conn, PAGE_BEGIN, strlen((char*)PAGE_BEGIN), NETCONN_COPY);
  netconn_write(conn, PAGE_BODY, strlen(PAGE_BODY), NETCONN_COPY);
}
```

Here is the part of the Java application I am using to make GET requests.

```html
    try {
          url = new URL("http://192.168.0.26/test");
          con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
          con.setRequestMethod("GET");
          con.setDoOutput(true);
          int status = con.getResponseCode();
          InputStreamReader streamReader;   
          System.out.println(status);
          if (status > 299) {
                streamReader = new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream());
          } else {
                BufferedReader in;
                streamReader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
                in = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
                content.append("test");
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(inputLine);
                }
                System.out.println(content);
                in.close();
          }
          con.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        }
    }
```

The board IP is 192.168.0.26. When I set the code to make a GET request to "http://192.168.0.26/STM32F7xx". It does work just like browsers and the HTML file is printed on the java application console. if I switch it to "/test". The browser shows the value of the variable pageHits, and the stm32 server increments the variable every time a request is made. However, when I do "/test" on the Java application. I get this error.

```html
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:718)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:715)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1322)
at dataconverter.Reader.getConnection(Reader.java.260)
```

I used Wireshark to analyze the packet for the /test and /STM32F7xx between the browser and Java requesT for each route.

**/STM32F7xx from browser**

```html
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
GET /STM32F7xx.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 192.168.0.26\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://192.168.0.26/STM32F7xx.html]
[HTTP request 1/1]
[Response in frame: 124]
```

**/STM32F7xx from Java Application**

```html
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
GET /STM32F7xx.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_271\r\n
Host: 192.168.0.26\r\n
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://192.168.0.26/STM32F7xx.html]
[HTTP request 1/1]
[Response in frame: 37915]
```

**/test from the browser**

```html
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 192.168.0.26\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://192.168.0.26/test]
[HTTP request 1/1]
```

**/test from Java Application**

```html
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_271\r\n
Host: 192.168.0.26\r\n
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://192.168.0.26/test]
[HTTP request 1/1]
```

Comment: I tried running the javascript snippets. They failed.

Comment: @user4581301 The snippets aren't meant to be run alone. They are only the essential part of the code regarding the problem i have.

Comment: Perhaps `strlen(PAGE_BODY)` should be `strlen((char*)PAGE_BODY)` in the last line of the first snippet. Can you give the raw data buffer in wireshark when you test "/test from Java Application"?

Comment: 0000   02 00 00 00 00 00 14 7d da bb af 2d 08 00 45 00   .......}...-..E.
0010   00 c4 00 00 40 00 40 06 b8 b0 c0 a8 00 19 c0 a8   ....@.@.........
0020   00 1a ca 2c 00 50 17 0a cc 1d 00 00 39 8b 50 18   ...,.P......9.P.
0030   ff ff 2d 3a 00 00 47 45 54 20 2f 74 65 73 74 20   ..-:..GET /test 
0040   48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41   HTTP/1.1..User-A
0050   67 65 6e 74 3a 20 4a 61 76 61 2f 31 2e 38 2e 30   gent: Java/1.8.0
0060   5f 32 37 31 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 31 39 32 2e   _271..Host: 192.
0070   31 36 38 2e 30 2e 32 36 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74   168.0.26..Accept

Comment: 0080   3a 20 74 65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d 6c 2c 20 69 6d 61   : text/html, ima
0090   67 65 2f 67 69 66 2c 20 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70   ge/gif, image/jp
00a0   65 67 2c 20 2a 3b 20 71 3d 2e 32 2c 20 2a 2f 2a   eg, *; q=.2, */*
00b0   3b 20 71 3d 2e 32 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69   ; q=.2..Connecti
00c0   6f 6e 3a 20 6b 65 65 70 2d 61 6c 69 76 65 0d 0a   on: keep-alive..
00d0   0d 0a                                             ..i

Comment: @ofaurax I tired what you suggested it didn't work. Thanks for the help. The data buffer is above. Please let me know if you have any other suggestins